# Converting date string from dashes to forward slashes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert my dashed date 2013-12-11 to 2013/12/11 using the following function:

```
function convertDate(stringdate)
{
    // Internet Explorer does not like dashes in dates when converting, 
    // so lets use a regular expression to get the year, month, and day 
    var DateRegex = /([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)/;
    var DateRegexResult = stringdate.match(DateRegex);
    var DateResult;
    var StringDateResult = "";

    // try creating a new date in a format that both Firefox and Internet Explorer understand
    try
    {
        DateResult = new Date(DateRegexResult[2]+"/"+DateRegexResult[3]+"/"+DateRegexResult[1]);
    } 
    // if there is an error, catch it and try to set the date result using a simple conversion
    catch(err) 
    { 
        DateResult = new Date(stringdate);
    }

    // format the date properly for viewing
    StringDateResult = (DateResult.getMonth()+1)+"/"+(DateResult.getDate()+1)+"/"+(DateResult.getFullYear());
    console.log(StringDateResult);

    return StringDateResult;
}
```

As a test I pass var `myDate = '2013-12-11'` in and log out before and after the function but the format remains the same? Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong with this?

Here is a test **jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/wbnzt/

Comment: instead of regexes why don't you use datestr.split("-").join("/") ?

Comment: Yes, what is the point of creating an intermediary Date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is working as expected convertDate(myDate) is returning the / value off the date.

Your problem seems to be your logging

```
var myDate = '2013-12-11';
console.log('Before', myDate); //2013-12-11

convertDate(myDate);
console.log('After', myDate); //2013-12-11
```

Your function returns a value so convertDate(myDate) is just returning and doing nothing. And your console log for after is just returning the same date as before.

If you change your console log to

```
console.log('After', convertDate(myDate)); //2013-12-11
```

You will get the expected result, or set myDate to the new value

```
  myDate = convertDate(myDate);
    console.log('After', myDate); //2013-12-11
```

Comment: Why doesn't he just split the String? I honestly don't understand this.

Comment: Yer splitting the string is the simplest solution, but I thought I would show where he was going wrong with his example to help as there where other answers showing how to split the string

Comment: I got that (and nice catch by you), but, I don't understand why he would do this!

Answer (score 6):

Use String Replace to replace the dashes with slashes.

```
string.replace(/-/g,"/")
```

Comment: am I doing this correct: var myDate = '2013-12-11';
console.log('Before', myDate);

myDate.replace(/-/g,"/")
console.log('After', myDate);

still seem to get the same result of 2013-12-11?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I misunderstand the question; why not just this:

```
function convertDate(stringdate)
{
    stringdate = stringdate.replace(/-/g, "/");
    return stringdate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
myDate.split("-").join("/")
```

Logic:
Split it by dash.
Join it by Slash.